VRP: how to reset a dimension to 0 at certain nodes?
When trying to solve the VRP (vehicle routing problem) with ortools in python, I have actual locations duplicated into several nodes (due to pickup-delivery constraints). A minimized version of my problem goes as follows. Each route (which starts and ends at depot location) may visit at most 3 nodes (depot + 2 stores). However, a vehicle may return to the duplicated depot, and make several routes. The vehicle itself may visit as many nodes as necessary.
How can I reset the values of the dimension that counts actual visited locations to 0 whenever the vehicle visits a copy of the depot? Here is a minimal example of code:
from ortools.constraint_solver.pywrapcp import RoutingIndexManager, RoutingModel, DefaultRoutingSearchParameters
from ortools.constraint_solver.routing_enums_pb2 import FirstSolutionStrategy, LocalSearchMetaheuristic
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

def solve_mixed_vrp(dist, n_vehicles):
   manager = RoutingIndexManager(len(dist), n_vehicles, 0)
   model = RoutingModel(manager)
   _node, _idx = manager.IndexToNode, manager.NodeToIndex

   model.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(model.RegisterTransitCallback(
      lambda _i, _j: dist[_node(_i), _node(_j)]))
    
   def route_locations(_i, _j):  # count how many different locations the route visits
      return 1 if nodes.at[_node(_i),'lct'] != nodes.at[_node(_j),'lct'] else 0
   model.AddDimension(model.RegisterTransitCallback(route_locations), 0, 3, True, "route_locations")
   dim = model.GetDimensionOrDie("route_locations")
   for i in range(len(nodes)):  # unsuccessful at setting dim at depot to 0
      if nodes.at[i,'lct'] == 0:  # check if node is the depot
         dim.CumulVar(_idx(i)).SetValue(0)

   search_params = DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
   search_params.local_search_metaheuristic = LocalSearchMetaheuristic.AUTOMATIC
   search_params.first_solution_strategy = FirstSolutionStrategy.AUTOMATIC
   return model.SolveWithParameters(search_params)

# Example usage: nodes are 0,...,5, locations are 0,0,...,4; there should be a solution 0 2 3 1 4 5
nodes = pd.DataFrame({"lct":[0,0,1,2,3,4]})  # original (non-duplicated) locations
nn, nv = len(nodes), 1  # number of nodes/vehicles
dist = (np.ones((nn,nn))-np.identity(nn)).astype(int);   display(dist)
sol = solve_mixed_vrp(dist, nv)
sol is not None  # check if a solution was found

The above attempt unsuccessfully resets the dim to 0 at depot, because there is no solution found.
Note: A similar question was asked here, but I was not able to decypher how to use the answer in my case.

Any answer or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.
